# Add non-github dependencies to github R package?

Tags: r, github, package

I am building an R package and posted it on github. It is supposed to depend on `stringr` ...  yet despite adding it to the "depends" and "imports" portions of the DESCRIPTION, it seems to have issues installing automatically (is it looking for `stringr` on github also?).

Here is the command I am running (imagine a fresh R install):

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tcarpenter216/packagename")
```

[replaced my packages name above with 'package name'] ... this is returning the following error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo tcarpenter216/packagename@master
Error in pull_off("#(.*)$") : 
  cannot open file         '/Users/tcarpenter/Library/R/3.2/library/stringr/R/stringr.rdb': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to put dependencies on a package hosted on github? Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have to have something in the namespace file, too. you can't just put it in the description

Comment: Wrong. Dependencies go into `DESCRIPTION`.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing packages, packages dependencies and what repositories such as [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) can do -- with just dropping code onto GitHub.

GitHub source code repositories do *not* resolve dependencies.

GitHub source code repositories are *not* R code repositories.

However, you can turn them into such R code repositories, and that is what my [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) packages (on CRAN and GitHub) does.  So see its simple documentation, included in the package. It fills the void you identified here.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify (as I'm not 100% sure I'm following), .... so if I have a package posted on GitHub, there is no way I can have it "auto-install" dependencies from CRAN?

Comment: You can have dependencies installed by `install.packages()` if these dependent packages are on repos that your R session knows about.  So simply put if you have a package in a drat on GitHub, its dependencies from other known repos (ie CRAN, the same drat, other repos you already declared, ...) then it works -- because `install.packages()` supports that.

Comment: Got it. So how would I add the "install.packages()" command to my package to get it to do as you say? Would I put that in a function?

Comment: Oh I see. You are suggesting that users manually install necessary dependencies? I know there is a way to make it such that when a user installs your package, R goes and installs dependencies automatically. It just sounds like that is not possible if my package is on github.

Comment: It does when you do what I said.